# Why gfortran does not give symbolic backtrace?

Tags: debugging, gfortran, backtrace

After I ran my fortran code with gfortran compiler using with –g otion I get the following error:

```
Program received signal SIGFPE: Floating-point exception - erroneous   arithmetic operation.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7F2EE30E57D7
#1  0x7F2EE30E5DDE
#2  0x7F2EE2820D3F
#3  0x7F2EE2DEC913
#4  0x408A97 in __aerosols_MOD_moment_logn at aerosols.f90:45
#5  0x408A02 in __aerosols_MOD_set_aerosol at aerosols.f90:78 (discriminator 20)
#6  0x6D357B in __test_cases_2d_MOD_standard_2d_cases at test_cases_2d.f90:210
#7  0x67E9FC in __set_profiles_MOD_read_profiles_standard at set_profiles.f90:118
#8  0x463BF8 in __main_MOD_main_loop at main.f90:48
#9  0x401F05 in kid at KiD.f90:17
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

I do not understand why the first four backtraces does not inform about the error trace. I tried addr2line to find the address but it also does not give information. How can I get to know the error traces?

Answer (score 2):

The symbolic backtraces printed by gfortran are not done by gdb, but rather by addr2line. The problem is that addr2line inspects the binary on disk and not the program image in memory. Thus for shared libraries, which are loaded into memory at some random offset (for security reasons), addr2line cannot translate the addresses into symbol names and thus the gfortran backtrace mechanism falls back to printing the addresses.

You can work around this by compiling statically, allowing addr2line to translate addresses in libgfortran, the gfortran runtime library. Usually the first few stack frames are from the libgfortran backtrace printing functionality, in any case.

Comment: +1 for likely correct explanation (addr2line can only handle one binary at a time). -1 for suggesting static linking.

Comment: I succeeded to solve the matter with `gdb`. I typed `gdb KiD_SC_2D.exe` and after the crash point the `(gdb) run` command wrote the error backtraces.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not understand why the first four backtraces does not inform about the error trace.

The stack trace you got is from some kind of internal Fortran error reporting mechanism, and not from GDB as your question implies. That mechanism is likely not handling shared libraries (note that all the "missing" frames are very far from application frames -- the missing frames are likely in a shared library).

Solution: run the program under GDB, and use `where` command. GDB knows how to read symbol info for shared libraries, and is likely to give you the missing info.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can wind up with some stack frames that don't have useful information.

One way is if your program has a bug and trashes the stack.  In this case I would suggest turning to `valgrind` to find the problem.

Another way is if the code in question was compiled without debuginfo.  Sometimes you may still get some information here, but not always.  In this case the solution is to recompile the code with `-g`.

A third way is if your program contains a just-in-time compiler and the execution stops in JITted code.  I suspect this isn't your issue, given that you're working in FORTRAN.

One way to tell where the code may have come from is to use `info shared` or `info proc mappings`, and search though the list of addresses to see where the PC values from the offending frames fit it.  (Yes, it's unfortunate to do this by hand.)  If the PC fits into one of the maps listed, then you know where to look to fix the `-g` problem.  If it doesn't fit anywhere, then most likely the stack is trashed.

Comment: You are assuming OP got a stack trace from GDB. He didn't. The solution is likely to run *under* GDB.

Comment: I tried the `gdb ./KiD_SC_2D.exe (gdb) where` but it resulted `No stack`. Ater I had installed valgrind-3.10.1 I also tried `valgrind --tool=memcheck KiD_SC_2D.exe` it resulted `valgrind: KiD_SC_2D.exe: command not found
`. What I did wrong?

Comment: @Beata "(gdb) where" -- you need to actually *run* the application until crash point, and use `where` only *then*.

Comment: I had run `gdb KiD_SC_2D.exe` and after the crash point I write only `where` option and I got No stack.

Comment: I tried run the model with `-static-libgfortran` option but I got two extra backrtace errors: `0x6FCF8D in _gfortrani_backtrace` and `0x6E87F0 in _gfortrani_backtrace_handler
`. The model output is written netcdf file. The netcdf C and the Fortran netcdf libraries are installed as shared libraries and the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set by `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH={NCPATH}/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}`. I do not know if it may have caused the matter?